# parse data set in python with complex list structure

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a data set that I'm trying to parse and create a new list from. A sample is shown below:

```
(089964, 64509, 4890, 517, [
innerArray(a=789454, b=789454, c=56, o=1, d=66, e=63), 
innerArray(a=789454, b=789454, c=56, o=1, d=66, e=63), 
innerArray(a=788878, b=768910, c=112, o=2, d=66, e=63), 
innerArray(a=788878, b=928718, c=2464, o=44, d=66, e=63), 
innerArray(a=789454, b=789454, c=56, o=1, d=66, e=63)])
(089967, 64534, 4825, 517, [
innerArray(a=567454, b=789454, c=56, o=1, d=66, e=63), 
innerArray(a=567454, b=789454, c=56, o=1, d=66, e=63), 
innerArray(a=876878, b=768910, c=112, o=2, d=66, e=63), 
innerArray(a=876878, b=928718, c=2464, o=44, d=66, e=63), 
innerArray(a=875454, b=789454, c=56, o=1, d=66, e=63)])
```

I'm using a very simple code to extract what I need:

```
for i in tempFullList:
    print i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4]
```

where `089964, 64509, 4890, 517` are `i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3]` respectively and the entire `innerArray` is `i[4].`

What I'm really looking forward to is a list that has in each row i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],and each element of innerarray. For example:

```
(089964, 64509, 4890, 517,789454,789454,56,1,66,63), ...
```

InnerArray is the typename of the namedtuple that was created when parsing a log file.
I'm working on a code that can iterate through all innerArray (size not fixed), and some help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking for help with code, showing the code that you need help with is usually helpful.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sure. This is the farthest I could get from an already complicated file to be parsed. But I'll try to give one that is working on the data I've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `innerArray` is a class and accessing elements from it works like `ia.a`, `ia.b` etc. where `ia` is an `innerArray` object, here's something you could do (xs is your entire tuple):

```
 result = []
 common = xs[:4] # The first 4 elements, which will be common
 xs = xs[4:]     # The list of innerArray elements
 for x in xs:
     result.append(common[:]) # Makes a copy of the common list
     result[-1].extend([x.a, x.b, x.c, x.o, x.d, x.e]) # Or however you want to get the elements out of the "innerArray"; -1 selects the last inserted list.
```

It is much easier for people to answer your questions if you give us as many details as you can about your code, like for example, innerArray here.

EDIT: Just noticed you have multiple tuples like `xs`, in which case, just iterate over the list of tuples, and for each tuple, do the above.

Comment: I think in the 3rd line you meant a different variable than xs, right?

Comment: also, I'm getting an error if I reuse your code - `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'a'`

Comment: You could use a different variable, but I intentionally used `xs`. Regarding the `AttributeError`, can I see your full code? Maybe update your question?